# Randomly getting Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 “The network connection was lost.”

Tags: ios, networking, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession, nsurl

I'm randomly getting Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 “The network connection was lost.”
I immediately try again and it works. Different devices with different networks. Also happens when using WiFi on the device or simulator.
What is the issue?

Comment: Do you solve this issue? I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Typically, it means that the network connection is being lost.  When this happens, ask reachability to tell you when it's a good time to try again, then try again.

IIRC, it also can occur with certain programming errors that cause some servers to drop the connection immediately, such as trying to pass a request body in a GET request, but I may or may not be remembering correctly.

Comment: I immediately try again and it works. Different devices with different networks...

Comment: Probably caused by switching cell towers or something similarly innocuous that shouldn't cause a failure but sometimes does.

Comment: Also happens when using WiFi on the device or simulator

Comment: That's probably an indication that the server is dropping the connection for some reason, then.  Check the server logs for interesting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self.manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"close" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
```